# Typescript compile to single file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TS 1.7 and I'm trying to compile my project to one big file that I will be able to include in my html file.

My project structure looks like this:

```
-build // Build directory
-src // source root
--main.ts // my "Main" file that uses the imports my outer files
--subDirectories with more ts files.
-package.json
-tsconfig.json
```

my tsconfig file is:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module":"amd",
    "target": "ES5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "outFile":"./build/build.js",
    "sourceRoot": "./src/",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

When I build my project I expect the build.js file to be one big file compiled from my source.
But ths build.js file is empty and I get all of my files compiled o js files.

Each of my TS files look a bit like this

```
import {blabla} from "../../bla/blas";

export default class bar implements someThing {
    private variable : string;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: My favorite way to accomplish this is with esbuild. It is written in go and therefore is much faster than TSC and 100x faster than webpack. See https://esbuild.github.io/. It supports the outFile and outDir options.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will be implemented in **TypeScript 1.8**. With that version the **outFile** option works when **module** is **amd** or **system**.

At this time the feature is available in the development version of Typescript.
To install that run:

```
$ npm install -g typescript@next
```

For previous versions even if it's not obvious the **module** and the **outFile** options can not work together.

You can check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1544) issue for more details.

---

If you want to output a single file with versions lower than 1.8 you can not use the **module** option in **tsconfig.json**. Instead you have to make namespaces using the **module keyword**.

Your **tsconfig.json** file should look like this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "./build/build.js",
    "sourceRoot": "./src/",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Also your TS files should look like this:

```js
module SomeModule {
  export class RaceTrack {
    constructor(private host: Element) {
      host.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
    }
  }
}
```

And instead of using the import statement you'll have to refer to the imports by namespace.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (ev: Event) => {
  var racetrack = new SomeModule.RaceTrack(document.getElementById("content"));
});
```

Comment: The issue that you pointed out seemed to be resolved, also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options
suggests that the --outFile flag as to be used with the --module flag.

Comment: indeed, but it does not seem to be working. :( Maybe make an issue out of it on github?

Comment: btw, the resolutions of the issues on github do not seem to point to any actual changes to the code base, they always close with this being the default behaviour.

Comment: I just noticed this. It looks like the fix for the issue I mentioned will be available in version 1.8. Maybe use typescript@next to get the latest now? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes

Comment: And I can confirm this. if using typescript@next this works just fine. :) I'll edit my answer to include this too.

Comment: @toskv My *module* is set to *commonjs* and my output file is still empty, is this to be expected too?

Comment: if you are using typescript 1.7.5 (latest released) yes

Comment: it's just something that was never implemented. if you want to use it though you can get the development version of tsc. just run: npm install -g typescript@next

Comment: Understand now, sorry I'm a bit slow sometimes!

Comment: I edited the answer to include the @next part too, just so it's clearer. :)

Comment: @toskv and what if I want to compile each directory to its own file? For example I have `script/x/a.ts`, `script/x/b.ts`, `script/y/c.ts`, `script/y/d.ts`, `script/y/e.ts` and I want to get `script/x.js` and `script/y.js`. Now I'm adding `tsconfig.json` in each folder which combines all script files into one, but I'm looking for more elegant solution, because I want to have only one single `tsconfig.json` for such case. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I could see that doable with something like gulp-typescript. with tsc alone you'll need a tsconfig in each folder that you want compiled separately (as far as I know).

Comment: Is there a better way to do this with TypeScript 3.x?

Comment: @vitaly-t not natively, but there's a neat way with [ncc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/ncc). Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175555/3873510).

Answer (score 84):

### Option 1 - if you are not using modules

If your code contains only regular Typescript, without modules (import/export) you just need to add parameter `outfile` to your `tsconfig.json`.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "rootDir": "./src/",
        "outFile": "./build/build.js"
    }
}
```

But this option have some limitations.

If you get this error:

```
Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'
```

Try "Option 2" below.

### Option 2 - using a module loader

If you are using modules (import/export), you will need a module loader to run your compiled script in the browser.

When you compile to a single file (using `outFile`), Typescript natively supports compiling to `amd` and `system` module loaders.

In tsconfig, you need to set `module` to `amd` or `system`:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "AMD",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "rootDir": "./src/",
        "outFile": "./build/build.js"
    }
}
```

If you choose AMD, you need to use the `require.js` runtime. AMD requires an AMD loader, require.js is the most popular option (https://requirejs.org/).

If you choose System, you need to use the SystemJS module loader (https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

### Option 3 - use a module bundler / build tool

Probably, the best option is to use a module bundler / build tool, like Webpack.

Webpack will compile all your TypeScript files to a single JavaScript bundle.

So, you will use `webpack` to compile, instead of `tsc`.

First install webpack, `webpack-cli` and `ts-loader`:

```sh
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli typescript ts-loader
```

If you are using webpack with Typescript, it's best to use `module` with `commonjs`:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "rootDir": "src"
    }
}
```

Webpack `webpack.config.js` example:

```js
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: {
    main: "./src/YourEntryFile.ts",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: "[name]-bundle.js" // <--- Will be compiled to this single file
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Now, to compile, instead of executing using `tsc` command, use `webpack` command.

`package.json` example:

```
{
  "name": "yourProject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack" // <---- compile ts to a single file
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

[Webpack's TypeScript Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

Lastly, compile everything (under watch mode preferably) with:

```sh
npx webpack -w
```

Comment: Your solution does not work. I get "Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'."

Comment: @AlkisMavridis same for me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlkisMavridis I updated my answer with other options to compile to a single file, if you are using modules.

Comment: Don't forget to also install the CLI with `npm i webpack-cli` and neatly run Webpack on watch mode with `npx webpack -w`.

Comment: What file is that last one where I put 'scripts.build' to 'webpack'?

Comment: @JohnF That file is the "package.json" and is located at root directory. I updated the answer. https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 28):

### The Easiest Way

You can do this with a custom tool called [ncc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/ncc), built and maintained by [Vercel](https://vercel.com). Here's how they're using it in [create-next-app](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app):

```sh
ncc build ./index.ts -w -o dist/
```

Install it with yarn:

```sh
yarn add @vercel/ncc
```

Or npm:

```sh
npm install @vercel/ncc
```

Comment: Does this create a code that you can run directly in the browser ?
My browser says that "__dirname" is not defined

Comment: I don't know, but based on what you shared, the answer seems to be no. `__dirname` is a node.js-specific environment variable.

Comment: ncc is for Node.js project, eg if you want to build your database seeding scripts from TypeScript to JavaScript. Often those scripts are written "by hand" in JavaScript, with ncc you can instead reuse the code you have written in TypeScript for your app.

Comment: @rambi You can run it in the browser with a small hack. In your HTML file, add `var __dirname = "", module = {}` somewhere before the output from `ncc`. It's probably easiest to do it in a separate script tag.

Answer (score 2):

I similarly needed to compile multiple typescript files with import and exports to a single JS file, and found a solution.

1. Use this tsconfig to generate a single JS file with the System module. This tsconfig should be placed wherever you have your typescript files. Run `tsc` to generate the single js file

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
      "module" : "System",
      "declaration" : false,
      "baseUrl" : "./",
      "outFile" : "../libs/bundle.js",
      "alwaysStrict" : true,
      "removeComments" : true,
  },
  "include": [
      "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "./out.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

2. In your index.html you will need to include the system.js bundle JS file (found at https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/dist/system.js). Additionally, you will need to append the systemjs extra naming support found at https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/dist/extras/named-register.js to system.js
3. Include your compile bundle.js file in your index.html
4. Include a script that imports all the named imports found in your registry.

(steps 2-4 shown below)

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script src = "libs/system.js"></script>
    <script src = "libs/bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
      Object.keys(System.registerRegistry).forEach((key) => System.import(key))
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I needed to do something similar to bundle my Lambdas. The thing is, I only wanted to bundle my modules into single files with their imports included from my own code, not the node_modules.

I ended up using `esbuild` to solve my problem:

```bash
esbuild ./src/lambda/** --outdir=./dist/lambda --bundle --platform=node --target=node18 --packages=external
```