# Angular CLI how to compile a specific ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular 2 project and using Angular CLI to create new components & services and build and I want to push a specific fix to production.

I have hundreds of components and files, don't want to compile everything and push to production only a specific change.

Is there any way to compile a specific TS file ?

Comment: just use tsc: [Typescript compile to single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474651/typescript-compile-to-single-file)

Comment: +1 @drewmoore
There is no way from compile a single `.ts` file out of the box currently with the Angular CLI.