# Typescript Modules Into Single JS file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs

Ok, I am complete lost with this. I have just started using Typescript with Grunt JS and need some help.

I have a working Grunt file thats runs my TS and then a uglify process for site ready files, here is the config:

```
  ts: {
        default: {
            files: {
                '/js/builds/main.js': ['/typescript/main/build.ts'],
                '/js/builds/public.js': ['/typescript/public/build.ts']
            }
        },
        options: {
            target: 'ES5',
            fast: 'never',
            sourceMap: false,
            allowJs: true,
            declaration: false,
            module: 'amd'
        },
    },

    'uglify': {
        options: {
            preserveComments: 'some',
        },
        my_target: {
            files: {
               'src/js/main.js': ['/js/builds/main.js'],
               'src/js/public.js': ['/js/builds/public.js']
            }
        }
    }, 

    watch: {
        'JS': {
            files: [
                   '/js/**/*.js',
                   '/typescript/**/*.ts', 
                   '/typescript/**/**/*.ts'
                ],
            tasks: ['ts', 'uglify'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        }
    }
```

So now I am working on my Typescript files, but I having a lot of issues, I want to use Typescript as a module system but to output into a single file, right now its set to AMD, which needs Require JS of which I dont know.

Right now I don't have the time to learn Typescript and Require JS. So where is what I have got right now,

```
test.js:

export class testMe {
    constructor() { }

    LogingData() {
       console.log( 'Data being logged...' );
    }
}
```

Then in my build  ts file,

```
import {testMe} from "./clients/clients";
```

However this needs Require JS or module loading system in order to get it to run? I have tried using commonJs but it seems support for that was removed in Typescript 1.8 (I am using 2.0).

So how do I get my Grunt / Typescript into a single standard ES5 complied code, while using modules for Typescript?

Many thanks

UPDATE

This question & answer, [Typescript compile to single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474651/typescript-compile-to-single-file) does not give an answer for how to setup grunt to use Typescript into a single file! Plus the answer states that Typescript 1.8+ will fix that issue - But the version I am using does not.

I am using Grunt to compile the TS code into one standard javascript file, without the use of System or Require JS. So I can use that within my HTML code.

The end goal would be to have two single files. To explain I have lots of single .ts files for two sections, one main and the other public - I have not work on the public section, just the main one, so all my tests I been on that section.

So to layout my file/folder path:

```
    js/
      builds/
          main.js < targer end file
          public.js <- target end file

    typescript
      main/
         settings/
              classA.ts
              somethingelse.ts
         othersection/
               something.ts
      buildMain.ts <- *1
```

*1 This file then takes all the ts files, via imports (not sure if thats the correct way) and then builds the complete standard single .js file.

I hope that explains my query in more detail.

Thanks

UPDATE 2:

I would just like to add that I am getting a single file, e.g. main.js but that is not a standard Javascript complied file. I don't want to use Require JS or any other external module loading system.

I want to use external .ts files has modules import them into a 'build' file and have that file compile down to a standard self contained javascript file without the need to include require js or anything else.

Hope that clears it up a little more..

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript compile to single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474651/typescript-compile-to-single-file)

Comment: I did look at that post, but it only says it can be done with TS 1.8+, but until use something else. But not how to do it, and it system that they all want to set the output file to a module loading system, which is not what i want

Comment: Try removing `module` and adding `outFile` to your ts:options.

Comment: @mike-mccaughan, I am not sure how that would work? I have two output files, one for my public area and one for the login user. I am guesting I could set up two tasks within the TS task. Got any ideas on how that could work? Thanks.

Comment: Your question specified you want a single file. Now you're saying you want two... Please [edit] your question to make it reflect your actual requirements.

Comment: Yeah I want one per section, if you look at the grunt config, I have one for public and one for main, so single files - I have not done anything for the public one anyway so the question still stands as is. The code I have tested with will only compile into a AMD or System module and not into a single standard javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use --outfile to get everything into one file. The trick is to remove import and export statements and use `/// <reference path="path/to/file.ts" />` on the first lines to declare the dependency / ordering relationships.  Since it is the import/export statements that produce the calls to CommonJS or Require, omitting them prevents their generation.

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

For two output files, you'll probably need two tsconfig.json. (I might be incorrect here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't bother with `.d.ts` files you can simply use just [`--module=commonjs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)(it is and will be supported) to compile each file into `.js` and then `browserify` to concat all modules together.

I'm using CLI scripts instead of grunt but it should be obvious what it does:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --module commonjs main.ts
$ ./node_modules/.bin/browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Then you can run it like any other JavaScript from browser or CLI using `node`.

There's also `--outFile` option for `tsc` but this is limited only to `amd` and `systemjs` modules so I think it's easier to stick to `commonjs` and `browserify`.

`browserify` is an amazing tool. You can generate UMD module with [`--standalone`](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#standalone) parameter that works also as global or [exclude any external dependencies](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#ignoring-and-excluding).

I highly recommend you to read the Official Handbook: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook

Comment: i did cover browserify a little in some research a while ago and it did look very good. But when I set my Grunt file to commonjs, it displays an error,  TypeScript 1.8+ requires "module" to be set to system or amd for concatenation of external modules to work. - And I dont really want to use another CLI tool, as this Grunt file deals with my scss code as well

Comment: @C0ol_Cod3r You already have `module: 'amd'` under `ts` so I guess you can change this to `commonjs. Running `browserify`` under `grunt` seems to be pretty well documented https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify

Comment: Yeah I didn't really think about that, I guest I could do that, but now I still need to learn more about browserify. My main aim here is to use Typescript as an ES6 to ES5 and to use some of the very cool stuff within TS - I see about browserify if I can not get anything else to work. Thans