# How to compile sets of .ts files ito a single .js

Tags: typescript

I want to compile a subset of my .ts files into a single .js file.  There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474651/typescript-compile-to-single-file) that addresses how to compile everything into a single .js file, but I just need a subset.

I've looked around tsconfig.json, but didn't see anything obvious.  Is there a way to do, preferably from the IDE (Visual Studio).

Comment: Looking at compiler options, it seems like you can create a rootDir, where you specify each subset, in that subset only imports are allowed similar to https://medium.com/@balramchavan/smarter-way-to-organize-import-statements-using-index-ts-file-s-in-angular-c685e9d645b7, then in your outdir, you would get a set of ts files, which would get the preferred result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `outFile` argument which is mentioned by the question you referenced but, as you state, it will compile everything into one file.  You could create a second `tsconfig.json` file (named `tsconfig.subset.json` or something) which uses the `includes/excludes` options to specify only the files you want but if any of the included files references any of the excluded files you will get an exception (e.g. the specific files must be self contained).

If you have a single file which you can use as an entry point that references only the subset of files you want bundled up you could use `rollup` or `webpack`.

Otherwise, if you just want to specify some specific collection of files that aren't really self contained I do not know any tools that do that.